# Visual Studio 2010 - Visual editor - Hiding the css guides (blue lines)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When selecting a control in visual editor, using absolute positioning on a webpage, I get these "guides" for aligning (top, bottom, left, right), accidentally clicking them results in the css property being set.

[image]

I find this very annoying and sometimes results in unwanted behavior of a control. So my question is, are there any way to remove/hide these guides?